# ASP.NET Custom control partial postback support

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a custom ASP.NET control. This control can be optionally rendered inside its own Update Panel and therefore support AJAX postbacks by nature. This design was opted in order to remove any external (page) dependencies on whether my control was placed inside a page level update panel or not.

I tried to use my control in a solution where it had to be placed inside a Panel that was ajaxified using Telerik's RadAjaxManager (please note that I tried the same setup using native framework's script manager and update panel instead of Telerik's RadScriptManager and RadAjaxManager). The page I used my control on was a Content page using a Master page.

The strange behaviour I observed is that a) some server child controls of my control (i.e. LinkButtons) correctly behave with a partial postback while others always cause a full postback and b) if I abandoned the scenario of Master/Content page and instead used a single stand-alone page, the LinkButtons behaved as expected (i.e. with partial postbacks).

The conclusion I came up with is that Master/Content page scenario (with the script manager being on the Master page and my control on Content page) causes the problem. However, and contradicting to my conclusion, this still doesn't explain why some child controls of my control behave as expected and others don't.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you check  if the buttons that are causing full post back are in update panel???

Comment: The button(s) causing full postback as well as those behaving normally, are all inside my control. I understand I need not register them individually